# Windows form button displays textbox and enter name to create new button

Tags: c#, windows, forms, button, panel

How can I do one button `show textbox`, inside `textbox` enter the name and press enter then it creates a button with the name that was placed in the `textbox` in a panel?.

Comment: Welcome and read [FAQ] first.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: BTW: No need to add the tags to your questions title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no InputMessageBox in C#.
But you can reference "Microsoft.VisualBasic" and dann using the Interaction.InputBox.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;


  // Click-Event
  private void btn_GetName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        string btnTxt = Interaction.InputBox("Title", "Message", "defaultValue", 10, 10);

        Button button1 = new Button();
        button1.Location = new Point(20, 10);
        button1.Text = btnTxt;
        this.Controls.Add(button1);
  }
```

This is a really simple Task, please use next time Google or post some Code to debug your Errors.

BTW: There are many other solutions for this here in StackOverflow.